# Display multiple columns in a Menu

Tags: java, swt

Currently I have a SWT Menu that looks like this:

[image]

I want the arrows to be aligned (one below the other). Text before the arrows is not always the same. My first idea was to change the font of menu items to some fixed font (Courer for example) and then I could move the arrows to the longest text length (just add spaces to shorter text).

But, according to [eclipse forum post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t26228.html) changing font to a MenuItem is not possible.
My other idea was to display TableViewer with 3 columns as a popup, but I have no idea how to do that.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220427/swt-table-combo-box  and http://www.coderanch.com/t/340213/GUI/java/Multiple-Columns-JCombobox

Comment: @RachelGallen The second link is for Swing, not SWT. And I can't see the relation of the first link to this question...

Comment: @Mikhail How will String.format help to align the arrows?

Comment: it would let you tune the white space use. Use format to print print the strings with certain padding.

Comment: @Mikhail that would work work with fixed size font (each character has the sam width) but that is not the case, as I explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a method, which computes the needed empty spaces between the columns. You need at first to find out the largest MenuItem text and then to add some empty spaces. In your example that would be "Some text0 some more text". It has 25 chars. Then you add the empty spaces (let's take for example 5). So the offset for the next Column shoud be 30 chars. For the every MenuItem you must add `30 - menuItem.getText().length()` white spaces. I hope you got my idea.

EDIT:
I didn't saw, that the font is not size fixed.

Another solution is the use of `\t` in the text. I've playes with the following example:

```
package la.la.la;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class PopupMenuCreate {

    MenuItem fileExitItem, fileSaveItem;
    static MenuItem helpGetHelpItem;
    static MenuItem helpGetHelpItem2;
    static MenuItem helpGetHelpItem3;
    static MenuItem helpGetHelpItem4;
    static MenuItem helpGetHelpItem5;

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Button bn = new Button(shell, SWT.FLAT);
        bn.setText("Right Click HERE to see the popup menu");

        final Menu helpMenu = new Menu(bn);
        final MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.CASCADE);
    newItem.setText("New");
        final MenuItem refreshItem = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.NONE);
    refreshItem.setText("Refresh");
        final MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.NONE);
    deleteItem.setText("Delete");

        helpGetHelpItem = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        helpGetHelpItem.setText("&Get \tHelp");

        helpGetHelpItem2 = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        helpGetHelpItem2.setText("&Gets \tHelp");
        helpGetHelpItem3 = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        helpGetHelpItem3.setText("&Getscccccc \tHdas sdad aasd");
        helpGetHelpItem4 = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        helpGetHelpItem4.setText("&Getscccccc asd sda \tsasa");
        helpGetHelpItem5 = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        helpGetHelpItem5.setText("&Getscccccc dsa  ddd asd das asd fdslfdsnjkl nsdjkl nsdjklm fsjkl \tLalalal");

        final Menu newMenu = new Menu(helpMenu);
    newItem.setMenu(newMenu);

    final MenuItem shortcutItem = new MenuItem(newMenu, SWT.NONE);
    shortcutItem.setText("Shortcut");
    final MenuItem iconItem = new MenuItem(newMenu, SWT.NONE);
    iconItem.setText("Icon");

        bn.setMenu(helpMenu);



    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT2: However this won't work either... It aligns the text to right.

Comment: I tried that. But it doesnt work with default font because character width is not the same (space is shorter than other letters). And I cannot change the font. I tried to explain that in the question.